# How to link between divs in twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap framework to make my website
http://www.keralatravelfriend.com
the navbars are working fine. 
but when i link to something like

http://www.keralatravelfriend.com/wayanad#hotels (there is a div called hotels which is id)
its not working. but when i click in the navbar "hotels" its fine. what to to. please help.

i have tried everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to triger onclick event on #hotels tab.

```
$('#link').click(function(){
  $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('#hotels').trigger('click');
});
```

The problem is when the link is on the same page the example below is working ....else if the link is on another page you need to triger after you get the #id from url. In this case You need to use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x = location.hash;
    $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find(x).trigger('click');
}
```

Comment: it may work but i found some other thing i have added this code to bootstrap.js  `$(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;

    // do some validation on the hash here

    hash && $('ul.nav a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
});`